# How to slow down MapView animation in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a line of Swift that sets the center of the map to an annotation that was tapped.

```
mapView.setCenter(annotation.coordinate, animated: true)
```

However, this animation is too **fast**. Is there a way to slow it down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call [`setCenter(_:animated:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1451976-setcenter), at this point. What you could do is to directly set a value for [`centerCoordinate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1451901-centercoordinate) inside `UIView` animation function:

```
// set your needed time per second, the current is 3.0 seconds
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3.0) { 
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = annotation.coordinate
}
```